# Django: how to filter on extra column?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a query like: `Foo.objects.extra(select={'extra_column':'SELECT ...'})`, and I want to filter on the `extra_column`, but I cannot get this alias on filter. I am thinking of using `annotate()`, but I don't know `annotate()` can using on `select`clause, all the tutorial is on `SUM` etc. I also tried `HAVING` clause, but it seems that Django doesn't support `HAVING` on `extra()`.

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Edit:

Django 1.6, MySQL

I am query on some complicated condition, so I must using `extra()` to write the subquery. But I cannot using `filter()` to access the alias of the subquery. If I turned to `annotate()`, which can be accessed in later `filter()`, but seems that it only works with `SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG`, thus I cannot use it on my custom `SELECT` subquery.

I read the similar question here: [Django ORM: Filter by extra attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348124/django-orm-filter-by-extra-attribute). It said that when query on a alias on MySQL, you need to use `HAVING` clause.

I don't know if this issue is also on other SQL backends like PostgreSQL, or on higher version of Django. Maybe there is no built-in solution on this question in Django1.6 with MySQL?

Comment: Can you explain what you trying to do with the extra query? Maybe it could be solved by doing joins or even a simple annotate. And also, which Django version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The as the correct marked answer, of the similar question, mentions; it is not possible to use a filter (because `filter()` only inspects model definitions). It suggest to use another `extra`, containing a where clause.

So something like;

```
Foo.objects\
    .extra(select={'extra_column':'SELECT ...'})\
    .extra(where=["extra_column = %s"], params=[value])
```

As of Django 1.7 you can work with lookups:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-lookups/

Comment: Actually extra will render where clause in SQL. But in MySQL, you need HAVING here. So I finally used the raw SQL.

Comment: This example does not work. It raises `OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'extra_column' in 'where clause'")` on MySQL database. You cannot use fields generated using `extra` in another `extra` clause.