# Django Queryset: Cast VARCHAR field in SQL before filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table that I cannot control, but need to select from it. The field "building" is a varchar, and also defined like this in my (non managed) django model. But it should be treated as integer, when selecting from that table (there are values like "000100", and even spaces at the end).

I need a simple filter like this:

```
.annotate(CastInt("building")).filter(building__castint__exact=my_id)
```

only problem is, CastInt does not exist. How could one achieve this? I was looking at .extra() (that we should no use anymore, as it's deprecated) and RawSQL, but hoping for a solution using only the Django ORM, without custom written SQL?

EDIT: currently using a hack from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348124/django-orm-filter-by-extra-attribute) (in the comments):

```
Address.objects.extra(where=('CAST(TRIM(building) AS UNSIGNED)=%s',),
                      params=(building_no, ))
```

works, but ugly.

EDIT II: See my accepted answer - using my second best friend, the regex.

Comment: any specific reason to cast to int??

Comment: if "my_id" is 100, it will not select the row with "000100"

Comment: casting is not needed if it "works" without. I saw other questions where __contains was used, but this will not work, as a row could have "100100" as building field value.

Comment: simply writing int(string with prefixed 0) automatically converts it to a real number

Comment: If you are using mysql, here's a way using raw sql, please check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query

Comment: the .extra()  I've added in the question works quite well, but I wonder if there is a better and DRY'er way..

Comment: I would argue that it's ugly or hacky. The purpose of `extra`, according to django docs is to add `a hook for injecting specific clauses into the SQL generated by a QuerySet.`, there's always some cases that orm doesn't cover enough. Beware though, if you change your database backend the raw query might not work.

Comment: completely agree. that's why I've not added it as my own response yet. also, extra is considered deprecated, so I'm not happy with this solution.

Comment: @ShangWang I know how to do it in sql, and yes, I'm using MySQL. I'm looking for a better solution, using the Django ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as simple as it gets: use a regex query

```
regex = r'^0{0,4}%s ?$' % building_no
address = Address.objects.filter(building__iregex=regex)\
```

any hints on performance welcome...

Answer (score -3):

try simple `int(you string value)`

for example:

```
str = "00100"
int(str)
```

will give 100 as integer value.
same applies for

```
 str = "100100"
int(str)
```

gives 100100 as integer

Comment: I already have a real int (that was cast, as you propose), that needs to filter my django queryset. The problem is the value in the db: it is "000100", and if I just do a Address.objects.filter(building=myfiltervalue), it doesnt not filter as I want (0 results)

Comment: myfiltervalue value is what?

Comment: I think @benzkji is asking for how to create a proper query, not how to convert between `int` and `str`.

Comment: yes got it .. i am still looking for the solution.. @ShangWang: do you have any idea ?