# Querying objects using attribute of member of many-to-many

Tags: python, django, postgresql, many-to-many, postgis

I have the following models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # some other stuff
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ref

class Feature(models.Model):
    feature_id = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
    # some other stuff
```

A Member is basically just a pointer to a Feature.  So let's say I have Features:

- feature_id = 2, members = 1, 2
- feature_id = 4
- feature_id = 3

Then the members would be:

- id = 1, ref = 4
- id = 2, ref = 3

I want to find all of the Features which contain one or more Members from a list of "ok members."  Currently my query looks like this:

```
# ndtmp is a query set of member-less Features which Members can point to
sids = [str(i) for i in list(ndtmp.values('feature_id'))]
# now make a query set that contains all rels and ways with at least one member with an id in sids
okmems = Member.objects.filter(ref__in=sids)
relsways = Feature.geoobjects.filter(members__in=okmems)
# now combine with nodes
op = relsways | ndtmp
```

This is enormously slow, and I'm not even sure if it's working.  I've tried using print statements to debug, just to make sure anything is actually being parsed, and I get the following:

```
print(ndtmp.count())
>>> 12747
print(len(sids))
>>> 12747
print(okmems.count())
```

... and then the code just hangs for minutes, and eventually I quit it.  I think that I just overcomplicated the query, but I'm not sure how best to simplify it.  Should I:

1. Migrate Feature to use a CharField instead of a BigIntegerField?  There is no real reason for me to use a BigIntegerField, I just did so because I was following a tutorial when I began this project.  I tried a simple migration by just changing it in models.py and I got a "numeric" value in the column in PostgreSQL with format 'Decimal:( the id )', but there's probably some way around that that would force it to just shove the id into a string.
2. Use some feature of Many-To-Many Fields which I don't know abut to more efficiently check for matches
3. Calculate the bounding box of each Feature and store it in another column so that I don't have to do this calculation every time I query the database (so just the single fixed cost of calculation upon Migration + the cost of calculating whenever I add a new Feature or modify an existing one)?

Or something else?  In case it helps, this is for a server-side script for an ongoing OpenStreetMap related project of mine, and you can see the work in progress [here](https://github.com/maxvonhippel/NepalOSMHistory/wiki/Cards-Server-API-%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD#second-json-object---initialized-on-selection-change).

**EDIT** - I think a much faster way to get `ndids` is like this:

```
ndids = ndtmp.values_list('feature_id', flat=True)
```

This works, producing a non-empty set of ids.
Unfortunately, I am still at a loss as to how to get okmems.  I tried:

```
okmems = Member.objects.filter(ref__in=str(ndids))
```

But it returns an empty query set.  And I can confirm that the ref points are correct, via the following test:

```
Member.objects.values('ref')[:1]
>>> [{'ref': '2286047272'}]
Feature.objects.filter(feature_id='2286047272').values('feature_id')[:1]
>>> [{'feature_id': '2286047272'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was wrong to set up the database using a numeric id in one table and a text-type id in the other.  I am not very familiar with migrations yet, but as some point I'll have to take a deep dive into that world and figure out how to migrate my database to use numerics on both. For now, this works:

```
# ndtmp is a query set of member-less Features which Members can point to
# get the unique ids from ndtmp as strings
strids = ndtmp.extra({'feature_id_str':"CAST( \
    feature_id AS VARCHAR)"}).order_by( \
    '-feature_id_str').values_list('feature_id_str',flat=True).distinct()
# find all members whose ref values can be found in stride
okmems = Member.objects.filter(ref__in=strids)
# find all features containing one or more members in the accepted members list
relsways = Feature.geoobjects.filter(members__in=okmems)
# combine that with my existing list of allowed member-less features
op = relsways | ndtmp
# prove that this set is not empty
op.count()
# takes about 10 seconds
>>> 8997148 # looks like it worked!
```

Basically, I am making a query set of `feature_id`s (numerics) and casting it to be a query set of text-type (`varchar`) field values.  I am then using `values_list` to make it only contain these string id values, and then I am finding all of the members whose `ref` ids are in that list of allowed Features.  Now I know which members are allowed, so I can filter out all the Features which contain one or more members in that allowed list.  Finally, I combine this query set of allowed Features which contain members  with `ndtmp`, my original query set of allowed Features which do not contain members.

Comment: I figured this out in large part using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28101648/1586231) and [this question, not the answers to it though haha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068949/django-queryset-cast-varchar-field-in-sql-before-filtering).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations):

```
okmems = Member.objects.annotate(
    feat_count=models.Count('feature')).filter(feat_count__gte=1)
relsways = Feature.geoobjects.filter(members__in=okmems)
```

Comment: I think you're onto something, but the "models.Count('feature')" part doesn't make sense to me.  A Feature has a many-to-many "list" full of Members, not the other way around.  `okmems` should contain members which point to Features in my accepted features list (which I successfully make).

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being unclear, I'd like to abstract as much as possible but obviously this is a bit of a gnarly, particular use case. Basically, I already retrieved all of the Features which do not contain any Members. Let's call that "Set A".  Now I want to get all the Features whose Members at the very least overlap with "Set A".  The operative issue appears to be the Member "ref" to Feature "feature_id" comparison, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think the root of the question is how to compare a CharField id to a QuerySet of BigInt ids.  I'm going to try going down [this path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2513473/1586231) and see where it leads.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow skipped the CharField part for some reason. Frankly, this seems like a bad database design to me. I have encountered a schema like this, and it was pure pain to maintain. On your issue - you might want to check id ordering in both `Member.ref` and your queries - `'1, 2, 3'` and `'2, 1, 3'` are different strings even though ids are the same.

Comment: Very true, on both fronts. I'll probably end up investing in figuring out how to migrate to BigInt on both tomorrow.