# Django queryset filter after a concatenation of two columns

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

Is there any way to filter a model using a concatenation of two of its columns? My model is like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

What I need is to filter after the concatenation of the two columns, if a user inputs A123 I want to be able to find any Item that has series and number like %A and 123% or %A1 and 23%
Is this possible using the django models? Or is it possible with raw sql?
I would rather not construct a new column with the concatenation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes that is possible; you will need to `annotate` the QuerySet with the concatenation of the fields, and that new "virtual" column will be capable of filtering.

[relevant documentation on filtering annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

[using `Concat` as an annotation function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#concat)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I am using django 1.3 so there is no Concat defined. I tried doing it like described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348124/django-orm-filter-by-extra-attribute/4348728#4348728
but I get some errors and I also tired doing it like this:
    invoices = invoices.extra(
        where=['CONCAT(document_series_name, document_number) LIKE "%F001%"'],
    )
but I got the same erros: 
tuple index out of range
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in execute, line 44

Comment: Well that's a version number I haven't heard in a while... The documentation is not even available anymore! I'm assuming you cannot upgrade for whatever reason - even if you really should, at least for security reasons. Anyway, your best bet is then probably writing raw SQL, maybe check whether `F()` expressions were available back then too.

Comment: Thanks, I will try, the answer is still valid thou, thank you

Answer (score 46):

In addition to what was said earlier, example:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
queryset = Item.objects.annotate(search_name=Concat('series', Value(' '), 'number'))
# then you can filter:
queryset.filter(search_name__icontains='whatever text')
```

Comment: It's a function you need to use if you want to use an actual string instead of a column name

Comment: This works for me.  But, I'm also trying to `order_by('search_name')`.  The query executes without error, but the items are not ordered correctly.  How can I order the results in alphabetical order by the annotated field, `search_name`?

Comment: @MikeyE: do you got an answer on your question? if yes, please share ;)

Comment: @mikeyE @cwhisperer The documentation on annotations (first link in my answer) explicitly says that `order_by` is entirely allowed (just a couple of paragraphs below the linked anchor), without listing any drawbacks, so your issue is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

I found my way, if you are gonna use some of ajax requests, then I started to use like this

in views.py

```
AllUser = User.objects.all()
users = []
for i in AllUser:
    if query in i.get_full_name():
        users += [{'first_name':i.first_name,'last_name':i.last_name,'full_name':i.get_full_name()}]

qUser = users
```

and in returned ajax page (in my case 'searchajax.html')

```
{% if qUser %}
  {% for i in qUser %}
    <p class="queryP">{{ i.full_name }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

it works very well for me :))

Another way is using annotate

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
author =  User.objects.annotate(screen_name=Concat('first_name', V(' ') ,'last_name'))
for i in author:
    print i.screen_name
```

it makes the same job too :))

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full example that shows how to filter based on the [`annotate()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and a [`Concat` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#concat).

```
# Tested with Django 1.9.2
import sys

import django
from django.apps import apps
from django.apps.config import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connections, models, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

NAME = 'udjango'


def main():
    setup()

    class Item(models.Model):
        series = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    syncdb(Item)

    Item.objects.create(series='A', number='1234')
    Item.objects.create(series='A', number='1230')
    Item.objects.create(series='A', number='9999')
    Item.objects.create(series='B', number='1234')

    print(Item.objects.annotate(
        search=Concat('series', 'number')).filter(
            search__icontains='A123').values_list('series', 'number'))
    # >>> [(u'A', u'1234'), (u'A', u'1230')]


def setup():
    DB_FILE = NAME + '.db'
    with open(DB_FILE, 'w'):
        pass  # wipe the database
    settings.configure(
        DEBUG=True,
        DATABASES={
            DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS: {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                'NAME': DB_FILE}},
        LOGGING={'version': 1,
                 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
                 'formatters': {
                    'debug': {
                        'format': '%(asctime)s[%(levelname)s]'
                                  '%(name)s.%(funcName)s(): %(message)s',
                        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}},
                 'handlers': {
                    'console': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                        'formatter': 'debug'}},
                 'root': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'WARN'},
                 'loggers': {
                    "django.db": {"level": "WARN"}}})
    app_config = AppConfig(NAME, sys.modules['__main__'])
    apps.populate([app_config])
    django.setup()
    original_new_func = ModelBase.__new__

    @staticmethod
    def patched_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' not in attrs:
            class Meta:
                app_label = NAME
            attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return original_new_func(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    ModelBase.__new__ = patched_new


def syncdb(model):
    """ Standard syncdb expects models to be in reliable locations.

    Based on https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.3
    /django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L285
    """
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
    with connection.schema_editor() as editor:
        editor.create_model(model)

main()
```